# OpenSSL: best way to sha256 hash two sha256 hashes

Tags: bash, openssl, sha256

I have two sha256 hashes as hex strings

```
HASH1=b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b878ae4944c
HASH2=7d865e959b2466918c9863afca942d0fb89d7c9ac0c99bafc3749504ded97730
```

now I want to create a new SHA256 that depends on these two hashes. Any two hex representations of the same hashes should in any case always result in a representation of the same binary hash (so for example if I go off the string representations, then it must be some canonical form of it, like ascii encoded lower case)

I know that I need to use an injective function, but what's the best way to go?

should I use the string values and some delimiter and then hash the binary representation of that hash (and rely on bash using ASCII encodinng for it)?

```
NEW_HASH=$(echo -n "${HASH1,,},${HASH2,,}" | openssl dgst -sha256 | sed 's/(stdin)= //')
```

Or is it better to convert the string representations to binary first and then do something with the binary representations before feeding the result into openssl?

Answer (score 0):

Crypto functions operate on raw bytes.  So, if given hex-encoded strings, it's generally a good idea to decode these strings first, then feed the underlying array of bytes into the crypto function.

In your case, you need to concatenate two hex-encoded byte arrays together, then take the SHA256 hash of the result.  There are two ways you can do this:

a)  Concatenate your two hex-encoded strings, then decode the concatenated hex-encoded string to a byte array, then take the SHA256 hash of the byte array.

b)  Decode each hex-encoded string to a byte array, then concatenate the two byte arrays together, then take the SHA256 hash of the byte array.

Both of the above methods produce the same results.

For (a), you can do:

```
{ echo -n "b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b878ae4944c"; echo -n "7d865e959b2466918c9863afca942d0fb89d7c9ac0c99bafc3749504ded97730"; } | xxd -p -r | sha256sum
```

Which produces:

```
fc87504c81f99f46407174938c24d0d0b6c65179565a2ac0fd6bd12c2016cbe8
```

For (b), you can do:

```
{ echo -n "b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b878ae4944c" | xxd -p -r; echo -n "7d865e959b2466918c9863afca942d0fb89d7c9ac0c99bafc3749504ded97730" | xxd -p -r; } | sha256sum
```

Which (as expected) also produces:

```
fc87504c81f99f46407174938c24d0d0b6c65179565a2ac0fd6bd12c2016cbe8
```